# How to avoid allocations in functional stateful components?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following component:

```js
function SomeComponent(props){

  const [isMouseOver, setIsMouseOver] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div onMouseOver={_ => setIsMouseOver(true)}
        onMouseOut={_ => setIsMouseOver(false)}>
          <img src={isMouseOver ? EditIconHover : EditIcon} alt="icon"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

New instance of arrow function is created on every render. It creates a closure over `setIsMouseOver` function, though this function never changes.

Sure, it does not drastically affect performance in this case, but I'd like to know how to avoid these unnecessary memory allocations.

Do I have to attach all dependencies required for event handler to DOM element

`<div data-deps={setIsMouseOver} onMouseOver={onMouseOverHandler} onMouseOut={onMouseOutHandler}></div>`

and then access `deps` property inside `onMouseOverHandler` and `onMouseOutHandler` functions?

Comment: Have you considered or would using `.bind` help? e.g. `onMouseOver={setIsMouseOver.bind(null, true)}`

Comment: @customcommander Doesn't bind create new instance every time it is called?

Comment: It does. I think that usually the "traditional" way to fix this would be to use a class-based component and assign methods as handlers which also involved binding them. So either this method never worked as I expected or somehow React "knows" it doesn't have to change. I'm definitely not the best React person and I don't like it much either :shrug: :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use memoization, although in this particular example its an overhead.

Refer to [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setIsEnabled(v => !v), []);

  const toggleRef = useRef();
  const setterRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    toggleRef.current = toggle;
    setterRef.current = setIsEnabled;
  }, [toggle]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(toggle === toggleRef.current);
    console.log(setIsEnabled === setterRef.current);
  });

  return <button onClick={toggle}>{isEnabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-58971368-Closures?]

Comment: This should also call allocations because the parameter of `useCallback` must be instantiated `() => setIsMouseOver(true)` with the closure over `setIsMouseOver`.

Comment: Where is the problem of having closure over a setter?

Comment: It's not the problem by itself, but to call `useCallback` hook you have to pass a function as a parameter. An instance! This instance is created on every render, and engine cannot avoid recreating it because it captures over internal variable which is `setIsMouseOver` function.

Comment: "This instance is created on every render" instance of who?

Comment: Of this `() => setIsMouseOver(true)`

Comment: I pass to `useCallback` only a single instance of `() => setIsMouseOver(true)` its is not re-created since then, I still don't understand what you expect

Comment: On every render function component is called. New scope is created, inside this scope you get new variable `setIsMouseOver` (which references same function, but this does not matter.) Then you call `useCallBack` passing arrow function as a parameter. This function must be recreated anew because it captures over `setIsMouseOver` variable existing in new scope of the running function.

Comment: "This function must be recreated anew because it captures over setIsMouseOver variable existing in new scope of the running function." Why it must recreated? It is not even called because of the dep array

Comment: It does not matter whether function is called or not. Function is the object, you pass the instance (reference) of this object to `useCallBack`. The function must "track" the exact version of `setIsMouseOver` variable, that is closure holding the reference to `setIsMouseOver` variable in this particular scope must be created and attached to the function.

Comment: Ok, so are you asking how to prevent the creation of "new variable `setIsMouseOver`" even though it is the same reference?

Comment: Not the variable, but the closure. Yes.